# how to end redirected execlp in c

Tags: c, pipe, exec, posix

I try to redirect the exec function input, output result with pipe. This code works fine,  however I can't exit the execlp function below, which always require new input, however I just want run it one time. How can stop it after first input.

```
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <sys/stat.h>
#include    <unistd.h>
#include    <fcntl.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <errno.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <signal.h>
#define ERR_EXIT(m) \
    do { \
        perror(m); \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
    } while(0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int chi_pipe[2], par_pipe[2];
    if (pipe(chi_pipe) == -1 || pipe(par_pipe) == -1)
        ERR_EXIT("pipe error");
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
        ERR_EXIT("fork error");

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(chi_pipe[0]); // I don't read in channel 1
        close(par_pipe[1]); // I don't write in channel 2
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        dup(par_pipe[0]);
        execlp("tr", "tr", "/a-z/", "/A-Z/", NULL);
        close(chi_pipe[1]);
        close(par_pipe[0]);
        _exit(0);
    }

    close(par_pipe[0]);
    close(chi_pipe[1]);
    write(par_pipe[1], "haha\n", 5);
    char buf[3024] = {0};
    read(chi_pipe[0], buf, 1024*3);
    printf("buf=%s", buf);
    printf("\n");
    close(par_pipe[1]);
    close(chi_pipe[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this.

move the close up so the read can know that it won't get any more.

```
    write(par_pipe[1], "haha\n", 5);
    close(par_pipe[1]);
```

you seem to missing a dup for stdout in the child segment too,

Comment: actually I want to read the execlp("tr", "tr", "/a-z/", "/A-Z/", NULL) result, with your answer I maybe read the result just once. For reading continuously make par_pipe[1] non blocking instead of closing it immediately.

Comment: @neouyghur yes, with read and write running in the same thread there's several different ways to deadlock yourself, with care non-blocking reads and writes can be used to enable handling of large volumes of data... it's sometimes easier to fork the producer or consumer off into a separate pprocess.